# How to select decay parameter in nnet R

Tags: r, neural-networks, optimization, nnet

I'm using the `caret` package's *train* function to optimize a neural net using `nnet`. I'm new to neuralnet modelling so this is a learning process for me.

My data has 17 input fields, about 10,000 records, and I'm trying to predict a binary outcome.

Using a grid search, I'm scanning a range of nodes from 3:16 and a range of around five decay values between 0.1 and 0.001.

The issue I have is that the training process always results in the maximum number of nodes possible being selected. This gives a good cross-validation Kappa score and high AUC, but it generalizes poorly to a holdout set, which feels like a classic case of overfitting.

My question is this: I believe the decay parameter should be set to penalize high node counts, but in a grid scan I'm simply determining the best fit - which means a low decay and high node count. Should I be approaching this differently: e.g. by fixing a decay value to determine a node count, then flexing the decay value in a second phase? What point does a parameter grid scan have here if it can minimise the "penalty" ?

Comment: Allow the decay to take values higher than 0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I would actully use some kind of cross-validation or leave-one-out approach to determine the error rate and the most appropriate node-decay combination.

It is a difficult question though. I usually set the decay first after I scanned the literature for reasonable values to this specific problem. Then I vary the nodes by looking at the test errors e.g. with LOOCV...

/Tobias